# Select lines without additional partition and merge lines into one record

Tags: sql

I am working on cleaning up a database of contacts. There are several duplicates (triplicates, etc) but there are some records that are unique. I added row_num to the table and would like to write into another table, those contacts that only have a Row_num 1 - meaning no duplicates, triplicates, etc. In the example below, it would select Jamy and Kris, but not Carrie.

> RowID_    Lastname_       Firstname_    Address_____        HomePhone_____       Birthdate_
>
> 1_____        Abbott_____         Carrie___       123 Main St____    N/A ___________            Null
> 2 _____       Abbott_____         Carrie___       N/A_______            513-123-4567______    Null
> 3 _____       Abbott_____         Carrie___       N/A __________           N/A _________            02/12/71
> 1_____        Abbott______         Jamy___         456 Elm St__     614-123-4567____    11/12/81
> 1_____        Abbott______         Kris____         789 Cooper Dr_  937-123-4567__    12/23/64

After that, I need to figure out how to merge lines together - which seems impossible given that the records have data in multiple rows. Using Carrie Abbott has an example, ideally I want to clean data so I end with

RowID    Lastname      Firstname     Address        HomePhone       Birthdate
1        Abbott        Carrier       123 Main St    513-123-4567    02/12/71

Any help you can provide would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: which dbms oracle or sql server or mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with a `group by`:

```
select lastname, firstname, max(address) as address, max(homephone) as homephone,
       max(birthdate) as birthdate
from <whatever>
group by lastname, firstname;
```

Under the circumstances, you don't seem to need the `rowid`.

Comment: That's much easier than what I was thinking! Quick question, because clearly I don't understand the Max() function. How does that work with VARCHAR data types? A to Z order? thanks!

Comment: @user3731025 . . . `max()` and `min()` work on string types.  The ordering is based on the collation of the column, which is usually alphabetical ordering.